# Excel: Why is VLOOKUP returning inconsistent and unexpected results?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm automating an Excel column to assign account values based on the vendor paid. For instance, if AT&T gets paid, the account value is `Utilities:Telephone`, and when the post office is paid, the account value is coded with `Postage and Shipping`. I'm using the following formula

`=VLOOKUP(B2,$E$2:$F$8,2,1)`

to calculate the value in the `Notes` column. the `ExpectedValue` is hardcoded, and `Valid` is based on whether or not `Notes` is equal to my `ExpectedValue`

If I did what I was HOPING to do, the `Description` is matched against my `LookupValue` and if it's a close match, the field is populated with the corresponding value from `DecodedValue`.

Based on that, line 1 is `OK`. However, lines 2-8 are `BAD`, somehow the lines are matching to and decoding as the first index value in my lookup table. Because the lines starting with `PAYPAL` are all `OK`, I thought it may be the spaces or punctuation in the lookup table. But, if that's the case, Lines 5, 8 & 15 should pass. So I thought that it was only matching the lookup if the lookup value was at the start of the cell. But then Line 1 wouldn't have passed.

15 Lines of CSV data, are pasted below and referenced above.

```
Line,Description,Notes,ExpectedValue,Valid,LookupValue,DecodeValue
1,DDA PUR ATT*PAYMEN 800-331-0500 TX 300100860296,Utilities:Telephone,Utilities:Telephone,OK,ATT*PAY,Utilities:Telephone
2,DDA PUR THE HOME D MILWAUKEE    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Repairs,BAD,NETFLIX,Supplies:Research
3,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Craft Service,BAD,PAYPAL,Supplies
4,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Craft Service,BAD,STONE CREE,Craft Service
5,DDA PUR WALGREENS SHOREWOOD    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Medical,BAD,WALGREENS,Medical
6,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Craft Service,BAD,THE HOME D,Repairs
7,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Craft Service,BAD,USPS,Postage and Shipping
8,DDA PUR NETFLIX.CO NETFLIX.COM  CA,Utilities:Telephone,Supplies:Research,BAD,,
9,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
10,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
11,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
12,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
13,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
14,DDA PUR THE HOME D MILWAUKEE    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Repairs,BAD,,
15,DDA PUR USPS 56064 MILWAUKEE    WI,Utilities:Telephone,Postage and Shipping,BAD,,
```

Comment: I don't think the "close match" is doing what you think it does. When you set `1` or `True` for the last argument in VLOOKUP function, it returns an approximate match based on assumption that the lookup column is sorted ascending order.

Comment: Ahh, crap...I thought it was more of a "contains" function. Back to the drawing board...and to rephrase a new question. :)

Comment: Yep you're looking for something equivalent to a `LIKE` function, which can be used to compare strings in VBA. I don't think there is a worksheet function equivalent.  This may or may not be useful for you:  http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/07/simulating-a-like-function/  -- or if you're comfortable with user-defined functions, the first comment at that link has a solution that might also be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained in the comments, the `range_lookup` paramater for `VLOOKUP` is not a fuzzy search. Rather, it assumes the list is in ascending order and finds the closest match.
Here's the array formula you should have used (entered used `CTRL`+`ALT`+`ENTER`)

```
{=IF(MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,$F$2:$F$8,"")))=MAX(LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,$F$2:$F$8,""))),"",INDEX($G$2:$G$8,MATCH(MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,$F$2:$F$8,""))),LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,$F$2:$F$8,"")),0)))}
```

And here's how it works:
One part of the formula gets repeated a lot: `LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B2,$F$2:$F$8,""))`
(I'm just going to use `LEN(...)` in the future to save space)
It gives us an array of integers based on replacing each `LookupValue` with blanks in the `Description` and measuring the length of the result. The shorter the length, the more of the text matched. Taking the `MIN` of that array tells us the longest `LookupValue` that exists in the `Description`. Of course, this also means that `THE HOME D` will always be beaten by `THE HOME DESIGNERS` or something so be careful / exact in your `LookupValue` field.
Getting that part out of the way, let's show the formula like this to make it simpler to follow:

```
{=IF(MIN(LEN(...)))=MAX(LEN(...))),"",INDEX($G$2:$G$8,MATCH(MIN(LEN(...))),LEN(...)),0)))}
```

The first part `IF(MIN=MAX)` checks to make sure that at least one of the `LookupValue` records exist in the description. If nothing does, then the `SUBSTITUTE` does nothing and every `LEN` value will be the same.

```
INDEX($G$2:$G$8,MATCH(MIN(LEN(...))),LEN(...)),0))
```

Once we get past that check, the real meat is in the `INDEX` + `MATCH` combo. We match the shortest length (i.e., the longest `LookupValue` that exists in the `Description`) in the array of lengths to give use the *first* `LookupValue` that was found. Plug that into an array of the `DecodeValue` and out pops the `Notes` value you want.

The key point is to make your `LookupValue` field as long and exact as possible to avoid duplicate matches and then everything should work fine.

---

Here's the CSV version of my results:

> Line,Description,Notes,ExpectedValue,Valid,LookupValue,DecodeValue
>   1,DDA PUR ATT*PAYMEN 800-331-0500 TX 300100860296,Utilities:Telephone,Utilities:Telephone,OK,ATT*PAY,Utilities:Telephone
>   2,DDA PUR THE HOME D MILWAUKEE    WI,Repairs,Repairs,OK,NETFLIX,Supplies:Research
>   3,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Craft Service,Craft Service,OK,PAYPAL,Supplies
>   4,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Craft Service,Craft Service,OK,STONE CREE,Craft Service
>   5,DDA PUR WALGREENS SHOREWOOD    WI,Medical,Medical,OK,WALGREENS,Medical
>   6,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Craft Service,Craft Service,OK,THE HOME D,Repairs
>   7,DDA PUR STONE CREE SHOREWOOD    WI,Craft Service,Craft Service,OK,USPS,Postage and Shipping
>   8,DDA PUR NETFLIX.CO NETFLIX.COM  CA,Supplies:Research,Supplies:Research,OK,,
>   9,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
>   10,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
>   11,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
>   12,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
>   13,PAYPAL           INST XFER,Supplies,Supplies,OK,,
>   14,DDA PUR THE HOME D MILWAUKEE    WI,Repairs,Repairs,OK,,
>   15,DDA PUR USPS 56064 MILWAUKEE    WI,Postage and Shipping,Postage and Shipping,OK,,